# Generation of graphs using d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, graph

How to generate 4 different graphs using d3.js in a single HTML page? I have tried,but when i execute it the previous one got replaced with the next graph. I want two graphs side by side or one after other, Can you suggest me how can I get graphs like that?
Below Code generates one Bar chart

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
  fill-opacity: .9;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}

</style>
<label><input type="checkbox"> Sort values</label>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Frequency");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

  d3.select("input").on("change", change);

  var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
  }, 2000);

  function change() {
    clearTimeout(sortTimeout);

    // Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
    var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked
        ? function(a, b) { return b.frequency - a.frequency; }
        : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.letter, b.letter); })
        .map(function(d) { return d.letter; }))
        .copy();

    svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .sort(function(a, b) { return x0(a.letter) - x0(b.letter); });

    var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
        delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

    transition.selectAll(".bar")
        .delay(delay)
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x0(d.letter); });

    transition.select(".x.axis")
        .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("g")
        .delay(delay);
  }
});

</script>
```

Below code generates pie chart

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.arc path {
  stroke: #fff;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.Positive; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

d3.csv("csvfile.csv", function(error, data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Positive = +d.Positive;
  });

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.Feature); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.Feature; });

});

</script>
```

(note : Like this I have to create 2 Bar chart and 2 pie charts)

If I combine both I cant see both charts together the charts , How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using the same variable `svg` for all the graphs? You need to define a new variable for each new chart e.g. `svg1` for first `svg2` for next.

Comment: @Razzildinho     I am new to d3.js ,,so don't know much details . Here for each csv file i have to generate bar chart & pie chart...now I have to 2 different csv files and I need to generate 4 graphs(Pie and bar) in a single page..how can i do it?